# I accidentally denied everyone access to my Amazon S3 bucket except the private vpc cidr. How do I regain access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I use s3 bucket policy as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "OnlyAllowMyVPC",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "denyOthers",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws-cn:s3:::devbucket",
        "arn:aws-cn:s3::: devbucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "10.192.0.0/19"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

10.192.0.0/19 is the CIDR of my VPC, and my VPC does not have Internet access.

Then, even from the ec2 in this VPC, I still cannot access "devbucket" bucket, but I can access other buckets. I don't know why.

Can anybody help me with that, thanks a lot!

One way is to [use root user to delete the bucket permission](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/), but it is hard for me to gain access root user.

Update:

The reason that I can access other s3 is because I add s3 VPC Endpoint. When I delete the Endpoint, then I cannot access any buckets.

Comment: You should probably do a `"aws:sourceVpc": "..."` comparison instead of an IP one.

Comment: Yes, but it too late, I cannot access this bucket anymore...

Comment: Then you are out of luck, too bad.

Comment: Restricting access based on private ips does not make any sense at all, if I create a VPC and assign the same CIDR range then I could access your bucket!? Not ideal anyway.

Comment: Now, I know it does not make sense at all. I learn a lot from this mistake.

Comment: If you has awscli in your ec2, you can use it to update the bucket policy

Comment: And enough permissions too

Comment: @AshBlake I do not have the permssion of updating...

Answer (score 0):

Try using VPC Endpoint for S3. Basically, It will allow EC2 instance from the private subnet to connect S3 in a more secure manner.